# UpDate table on SQL from PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables SQL:

```
Table LRU (ID_LRU, LRU) ==> (int Auto increment)
Table article(ID_Article, Designiation, ID_LRU) ==> (varchar,varchar, int)
```

I have 2 files `Equipement.xsls` and `equipment.xsls`, I import them from `PHP`

I did 2 functions (Almost similar) to parse the 2 files:

```
public function parseEquipement($filePath = null) {
        set_time_limit(0);
        $listEquipement = [];
        $count = 0;
        $chunkSize = 1024;
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader(PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filePath));
        $spreadsheetInfo = $objReader->listWorksheetInfo($filePath);
        $chunkFilter = new \Floose\Parse\ChunkReadFilter();
        $objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $chunkFilter->setRows(0, 1);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filePath);
        $totalRows = $spreadsheetInfo[0]['totalRows'];
        for ($startRow = 1; $startRow <= $totalRows; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
            $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow, $chunkSize);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filePath);
            $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, null, true, false);
            $startIndex = ($startRow == 1) ? $startRow : $startRow - 1;
            if($dataToAnalyse[0][0]==NULL){
                break;
            }
            if (!empty($sheetData) && $startRow < $totalRows) {
                $dataToAnalyse = array_slice($sheetData, $startIndex, $chunkSize);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $chunkSize; $i++) {
                    if ($dataToAnalyse[$i]['0'] != NULL) {
                        $listEquipement[] = new Article($dataToAnalyse[$i]['0'], '', $dataToAnalyse[$i]['1']);
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
            unset($objPHPExcel, $sheetData);
        }           


        //echo($totalRows);
        //echo($count);
        return $listEquipement;
    }

    public function parseEquipment($filePath = null) {
        set_time_limit(0);
        $listEquipement = [];
        $count = 0;
        $chunkSize = 1024;
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader(PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filePath));
        $spreadsheetInfo = $objReader->listWorksheetInfo($filePath);
        $chunkFilter = new \Floose\Parse\ChunkReadFilter();
        $objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $chunkFilter->setRows(0, 1);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filePath);
        $totalRows = $spreadsheetInfo[0]['totalRows'];
        for ($startRow = 1; $startRow <= $totalRows; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
            $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow, $chunkSize);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filePath);
            $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, null, true, false);
            $startIndex = ($startRow == 1) ? $startRow : $startRow - 1;
            if($dataToAnalyse[0][0]==NULL){
                break;
            }
            if (!empty($sheetData) && $startRow < $totalRows) {
                $dataToAnalyse = array_slice($sheetData, $startIndex, $chunkSize);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $chunkSize; $i++) {
                    if ($dataToAnalyse[$i]['0'] != NULL) {
                        $listEquipement[] = new Article($dataToAnalyse[$i]['2'], $dataToAnalyse[$i]['3'], $dataToAnalyse[$i]['5']);
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
            unset($objPHPExcel, $sheetData);
        }
        return $listEquipement;
    }
```

I did a 2 class PHP, one for the getters and setters and other for the request is the following:

```
public function save(....\Parse\Article $article){
        $LRU=$article->getLRU();
        $designation=$article->getDesigniation();
        $articleid= $article->getId();
        if ($LRU == "Unspecified") {
            $IdLRU = 40;
        } 

        else{
        if ($LRU != 'new'){
        $check= $this->_db->query("SELECT `ID_LRU` FROM `lru` WHERE `LRU` ='".$LRU."'");

    if ($check->rowCount() == 0) {
            $this->_db->query("INSERT INTO `lru` (`ID_LRU`, `LRU`) VALUES (NULL, '".$LRU."');");
            $requete2 =$this->_db->query("SELECT `ID_LRU` FROM `lru` WHERE `LRU` ='".$LRU."'");
            while($data = $requete2->fetch())
            {
                $IdLRU=$data['ID_LRU'];
            }
    }   
    else{
            while($data = $check->fetch())
            {
                $IdLRU=$data['ID_LRU'];
            }
        }}}
        if ($articleid == 'DIEPRESTATION' || $articleid == 'DIEDIVBIEN' || $articleid == 'DIEDIVERS' ){
            if(!($this->_db->query("INSERT INTO `article` (`ID_Article`, `Designiation`, `ID_LRU`) VALUES ('".$articleid."', '".$designation."', '".$IdLRU."');")))
        {   
                if ($LRU != 'new'){
           return $this->_db->query(" UPDATE  `article` SET  `ID_LRU` =  '".$IdLRU."' WHERE  `article`.`ID_Article` =  '".$articleid."' AND  `article`.`Designiation` =  '".$designation."' LIMIT 1 ;");
        }else {
        return false;}
        }
        else{
            return TRUE;
        }
        }
        else{
            if(!($this->_db->query("INSERT INTO `article` (`ID_Article`, `Designiation`, `ID_LRU`) VALUES ('".$articleid."', '', '".$IdLRU."');")))
        {if ($LRU != 'new'){
           return $this->_db->query(" UPDATE  `article` SET  `ID_LRU` =  '".$IdLRU."' WHERE  `article`.`ID_Article` =  '".$articleid."' AND  `article`.`Designiation` =  '' LIMIT 1 ;");
        }else {
        return false;}
        }
        else{
            return TRUE;
        }
        }


    }

    public function saveAll(array $listArticle) {
        $count=0;
        foreach ($listArticle as $article) {
           if($this->save($article))
            $count++;
        }
```

echo($count) // here it display 0
            return $count;
        }

I tried to display a variable `count` in the function  `saveAll` it return 0. I can't understand why however the same work for the other table and the variable `count` it return the best data for them just for this table `LRU`

And in the controlleur, I just did the function to import the files:

```
$app->get('/admin/update/article', function() use ($app) {
    $parse = new ....\Parse\Parse();
    $update = new ....\DAO\ArticleDAO();
    $filePathEquipement = __DIR__ . "/../../DATA/UpdateFiles/Equipement.xlsx";
    $filePathEquipment = __DIR__ . "/../../DATA/UpdateFiles/equipment.xlsx";
    $equipement = $parse->parseEquipement($filePathEquipement);
    $equipment = $parse->parseEquipment($filePathEquipment);
    $countEquipement = $update->saveAll($equipement);
    $countEquipment = $update->saveAll($equipment);

    $stat = stat($filePathEquipement);
    $dateImport = date(d . '-' . m . '-' . Y, $stat['mtime']);
    $date = new DateUpdate(null, "Equipement", $dateImport, getdate()['mday'].'-'.getdate()['mon'].'-'.getdate()['year']);
    $dateDAO = new DateUpdateDAO();
    $dateDAO->save($date);

    $stat = stat($filePathEquipment);
    $dateImport = date(d . '-' . m . '-' . Y, $stat['mtime']);
    $date = new DateUpdate(null, "equipment", $dateImport, getdate()['mday'].'-'.getdate()['mon'].'-'.getdate()['year']);
    $dateDAO = new DateUpdateDAO();
    $dateDAO->save($date);

    $result = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4>    <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> "LRU" update finished successfully!</h4> ' . ($countEquipement + $countEquipment) . ' Article(s) has been saved/modified.<br/>
                        ' . $countEquipement . ' --> Equipement.xlsx<br/>
                            ' . $countEquipment . ' --> equipement.xlsx
                  </div>';
    return $result;
});
```

The problem is all the other tables take the update but one table is `LRU` however the code is almost similar just the name of the file.
Please I do not ask to work for me, just a glance of my code, and tell me where is my serious fault to correct it. According my small experience I think the fault in the request.

Thank you.

Comment: No one will read this bunch of codes. Please read [mcve] and modify question accordingly.

Comment: Ok thank you, i will change it now.

Comment: After wrote the question, the site do not give me the access to post :( You can only post once every 90 minutes.